# WMI StartService Parameter

Tags: services, windows-services, wmi

I'm currently using WMI to start a service, which is nice.

But additionally, I would like to send a start-up parameter to this service.

Is there anyway to do this using WMI? I couldn't find anything so far.

Regards,

Thomas.

Comment: Have you looked at WMIC [Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)?

Comment: No, I'm new to WMI and I don't really know the available tools.

Comment: What kind of paramater do you want to start up the service with? Can you give an example of what you would like to do?

Comment: basically, I want to start a service (AX 2012) passing him some usual parameters. It seems that it cannot be done easily in WMI, so I came accross another solution, that I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done with StartService, at least not with arbitrary parameters, as the WMI StartService method is simply starting a service that's already defined on the machine.

The parameters to be used with the service are set during definition of the service (when it's added to the machine).

At best you might be able to get away with stopping the service, modifying the *ImagePath* key in its entry in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<service name>`) to change which parameter(s) you're passing, and then (re)starting it.

Here's a page from Microsoft explaining how to access the registry with WMI: [WMI Tasks: Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394600(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: In the end, in Dynamics AX specific case, this solution was the correct one.
the command "sc start [AX_NAME] -regConfig=[config]" didn't work, the parameter was ignored although it was working for other services I used for test purpose.
I have coded a C# method editing AX's registry key using the solution above and it worked like a charm.
Of course, the answer I've put (using sc start) is still good for other scenarii.

Answer (score -1):

I came accross the following thing, which seems to do what I want :

sc start [service] param1 param2 etc

Of course it cannot be remotely directly, thus I'll have to find a way to call it. But it's a good start :)